# usemin not upadating js for revved images from $http json request

Tags: json, angularjs, grunt-usemin

I'm new to angular and started a simple project from generator-angular.

There must be something not jiving with usemin and a $http request to inject the url from json.

I'm able to get the yeoman.png to work with the cache busting but for some reason loading an image url from a $http request to local json doesn't seem to work.

I tested the ng-repeat by replacing '{{project.mainImg}}' with the yeoman.png '{{image}}' and that worked.

This is only a problem after running grunt build and the cache busting is created.

gruntfile.js:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js',
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'],
    patterns: {
      js: [
        [/(images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

controller:

```
angular.module('testProjectApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.projects = data;
 });
 $scope.image = "images/yeoman.png";
});
```

html:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}" alt="I'm Yeoman"><br>

<div class="project" ng-repeat="project in projects">
  <a href="{{project.url}}" target="_blank" class="{{project.title}}">
    <strong>{{project.title}}</strong>
    <img ng-src="{{project.mainImg}}" width="100%" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: no. i gave up and went a less glamorous route.